# How to omit some specific data while using self join

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
from employee e 
join employee e1 on e.dept = e1.dept
where e.id <> e1.id and e1.ename = 'Jack Abraham'
```

This is my particular code for SQL, it's working fine I am not able to understand that why we are using name = 'Jack Abraham' in the particular code when I want employee should not be 'Jack Abraham'. Please clear my doubt

Comment: Please provide your sample data, that would help to understand the logic.

Comment: Please provide both **sample data** and **expected result**  Otherwise trying to explain that where clause is like trying to explain why Shakespeare used the words "to be or not to be" - it could be for any reason at all.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of your SQL query is:

1. Get all the records with ename = `Jack Abraham` (**e1**)
2. Then self join to get employees who is in the same department with `Jack Abraham` but not `Jack Abraham` (**e**: same `dept` but differ `id`).

So that query is not only to get employees whose names aren't `Jack Abraham` as you thought.

It's to get all employees whose names is not `Jack Abraham`, but their deparment has someone named `Jack Abraham`.

But even it's not the right query, in case one department have 2 people with same name `Jack Abraham`. It should be:

```
FROM employee e 
JOIN employee e1 ON e.dept = e1.dept
WHERE e1.ename = 'Jack Abraham' 
    AND e.ename <> 'Jack Abraham' -- e.ename <> e1.ename;
```

So you could try ask the one who write that query the true purpose of that.
Or you could ask your BA to get the requirement and rewrite the query.